# I have a HY093 Error in this php/pdo code, but I can't find it

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is a piece of php code that I've written and I get a HY093 error, which according to what I've read is either a binding error or an error regarding the number of parameters passed or their quality, but I dont see anything wrong with my code.

Could it be that some of the variables is null when I'm passing it to the statements?

```
$sth = $connection->prepare(

                         "UPDATE `user_settings` 

                          SET 
                            user_show_money                 = :user_show_money, 
                            user_show_stats                 = :user_show_stats, 
                            user_accept_messages            = :user_accept_messages, 
                            user_interact_with_activities   = ':user_interact_with_activities' 

                            WHERE 

                            user_id = ':user_id'"

                        );  

$sth->execute(
                          array(

                                ':user_show_money'               => $user_show_money,
                                ':user_show_stats'               => $user_show_stats,
                                ':user_accept_messages'          => $user_accept_messages,
                                ':user_interact_with_activities' => $user_interact_with_activities,
                                ':user_id'                       => $user_id
                            ));



    $sth2 = $connection->prepare(

                        "UPDATE `users`

                         SET 
                             user_name      = :user_name,
                             user_avatar    = :avatar_path, 
                             user_sex       = :user_sex, 
                             user_password  = :user_password, 
                             user_quote     = :user_quote 

                             WHERE 

                             user_id         = :user_id"

                        );
    $sth2->execute(
                          array(

                                ':user_name'    => $user_name, 
                                ':avatar_path'  => $avatar_path, 
                                ':user_password'=> $user_password,
                                ':user_sex'     => $user_sex, 
                                ':user_quote'   => $user_quote,
                                ':user_id'      => $user_id 
                            ));
```

Comment: why still you have **two** queries in your code? We are supposed to dig it up, which is erroneous one?

Comment: and yes, you didn't get out all the quotes

Comment: oops, I removed two quotes that I hadnt removed here, but they arent in my code. and what did you mean about me having two queries?

Comment: You have to learn to do such things without external assistance. Are you going to ask a question every time you left an extra quote in the code, aren't you?

Comment: I dont think its the quote thing, because as I said, I removed the quotes. I am not a php developer, I just happen to be pressed against the wall to write this php at this occasion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite surprising you cannot find anything as this question has been asked many many many times already. And answers were listed to you while you typed your question.

For some reason you put your placeholders in quotes while you shouldn't.

Comment: Well, you have to do it carefully. To write a correct query and to count number of parameters is not that hard a task.